# How to set custom cookieStoreId using contextualIdentities.create()?

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla

Using the following code I can create custom contextual identity in Firefox (also see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextualIdentities)). My question is: how do I set my own name for **cookieStoreId** property. Firefox will always name it like *firefox-container-XY* by default.

```js
function onCreated(context) {
  console.log(`New identity's ID: ${context.cookieStoreId}.`);
}

browser.contextualIdentities.create({
  name: "my-thing",
  color: "purple",
  icon: "briefcase"
}).then(onCreated);
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible because **cookieStoreId** name is always auto-assigned by Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

browser.tabs.create({
cookieStoreId: customCookieStoreId
});

Comment: This answer could be improved by citing the documentation for the API you used, formatting with a code block, and providing more context into how your solution fits in relation to the original poster's code.